# Julia and Lapack: pstrf multithreaded but trtrs not

Tags: multithreading, julia, lapack

My program written in Julia does not yield the expected computational performance. Basically the program first computes the Cholesky decomposition of a large matrix **A** using `cholfact!`, so that **A** = **L**'**L**. Then it solves **Lx** = **b** for different **b** using the backslash operator.

This results in straight calls to Lapack. The function `cholfact!` is implemented by `pstrf!` and the backslash operator uses `trtrs!`. These are the correct Lapack functions to use. While the function `pstrf!` is executed in parallel, the function `trtrs!` is not. The profiler tells me that most of the runtime is spent on `trtrs!`. The lines of code in my program are

```
F = cholfact!(A, :L, pivot = true)     # precomputation, executed once
```

and

```
x = F[:L]\b[F.piv]    # inside a loop, b is computed from x every step
```

Why is there a difference between the two Lapack functions? How can I get parallel execution of `pstrf!`?